# Multiple tabs on web page

Tags: java, html, jsp, struts

How can I add multiple tabs to a jsp page ? I'm using struts, are there any jsp tag librarys I can use ?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Struts2 has a TabbedPanel tag

http://struts.apache.org/2.0.11/struts2-core/apidocs/org/apache/struts2/components/TabbedPanel.html

here is an example how to use it:

```
 <s:tabbedPanel id="test" >
    <s:div id="one" label="one" theme="ajax" labelposition="top" >
        This is the first pane<br/>
        <s:form>
            <s:textfield name="tt" label="Test Text"/>  <br/>
            <s:textfield name="tt2" label="Test Text2"/>
        </s:form>
    </s:div>
    <s:div id="three" label="remote" theme="ajax" href="/AjaxTest.action" >
        This is the remote tab
    </s:div>
 </s:tabbedPanel>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here you can find a page dedicated to [Struts Tabbed Layout](http://struts.improve-technologies.com/faqs/tabs.html).

For Struts2 you can check RoseIndia's [tutorial on TabbedLayout](http://www.roseindia.net/struts/struts2/struts2uitags/tabbedpanel.shtml).

Comment: Checkout the demo http://struts.improve-technologies.com/demonstration.html page and download the source code http://struts.improve-technologies.com/downloads/DemoServeurDeNews.war and analyze it.

Comment: That actually will not work as org.apache.struts.util.MessageResources is referenced, this class is in struts.jar but I'm using struts2. I dont think layout has been updated for this ?

Comment: Just noticed your comment points to Struts2, I'll take a look, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I don´t know what you want to do exactly with the tabs, In my case I only want to show information in different tabs, I don´t need an action is trigger in every tab change.

For my purpose, I use jquery:

http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Tabs#overview

Comment: Thanks, but I think I'll stick with the struts tabbed layout